# Is it correct/natural to use an inanimate subject for causative HAVE?

Tags: causatives

> **The protocol** has me divide the area into several plots.
>   **The next trial** has the protagonist enter the cave.

The first sentence is mine, and the second was written by a non-native speaker while correcting one of my posts on Lang-8.

Is it correct and natural to use an inanimate object as the subject for causative *HAVE*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We often say things like:

> The recipe has you knead the bread for 20 minutes.
>
> This experiment has one working with strong acids. Wear protective gear.
>
> These instructions have me attaching flange A to flange B. I don't get it.

"has one" is formal and "has you" is informal and "has me" may connote that the speaker is a little frustrated or perhaps confused or experiencing some sort of difficulty.  The speaker is taking the generic thing personally.